# How can I determine if a radio button is checked already?

Tags: radio-button, cucumber, webrat, checked

I'm using webrat with cucumber and I would like to test if a radio button is checked already when I am on a page.
How can I do that ? I didn't find any step in webrat which can do that.

Answer (score 20):

```
expect(find_field("radio_button_name")).to be_checked
```

Answer (score 9):

```
input("#my_box").should be_checked
```

Comment: Seems this method no longer works. I'm using Capybara 2.4.1. The `find_field` method suggested by @evedovelli did the trick.

Comment: I would suggest not using "should be_checked" but instead: expect(find_field("my_boxt")).to be_checked

Answer (score 6):

There are cases when you cannot rely on checkboxes having ids or labels or where label text changes. In this case you can use the `have_selector` method from webrat.

From my working code (where I do not have ids on checkboxes).

```
response_body.should have_selector 'input[type=radio][checked=checked][value=information]'
```

Explanation: test will return true if body of document contains an radio button (`input[type=radio]`) which is checked and that has the value "information"

Answer (score 2):

Just changed a web_step checkbox to radio button

Add the following step to web_steps.rb

```
Then /^the "([^"]*)" radio_button(?: within "([^"]*)")? should be checked$/ do |label, selector|
  with_scope(selector) do
    field_checked = find_field(label)['checked']
    if field_checked.respond_to? :should
      field_checked.should be_true
    else
      assert field_checked
    end
  end
end
```

And you can write the following to check whether the given raido button is checked or not

```
And the "Bacon" radio_button within "div.radio_container" should be checked
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in checkbox matcher in web_steps.rb:

```
And the "Bacon" checkbox should be checked
```

However, you'll need to have a label on your checkbox that matches the ID of the corresponding checkbox input field. The f.label helper in Rails takes a string to use as the ID in the first argument. You may have to build a string that includes the field name and the checkbox name:

```
f.label "lunch_#{food_name}, food_name
f.radio_button :lunch, food_name
```

In any case, use this directive to see that you've got the HTML correct:

```
Then show me the page
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapped Jesper Rønn-Jensen his function + added name which is used by rails:

```
Then /^I should see that "([^"]*)" is checked from "([^"]*)"$/ do |value, name|
  page.should have_selector "input[type='radio'][checked='checked'][value='#{value}'][name='#{name}']"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    And the "Obvious choice" checkbox should be checked
```

Although it might be a radio button, but the code will work. It is just checking for a fields labelled with that text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `checked?` on your field

```
expect(find_field("radio_button_id").checked?).to eq(true)
```